# Vue Component with Webpack

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I think I may be suffering from brain-fog here. I want to just render a simple Vue Compnent using Webpack. The result from the code and config below just renders a `<hello></hello>` when compiled.

The error seems to stem from the `<style>` section of the Single File Component. Console gives error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: h1 is not defined
    at eval (VM659 index.js:12)
    at Object../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./src/components/layout.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=ecebbf8c&scoped=true&lang=css& (main.js:283)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:579)
    at eval (VM655 layout.vue:5)
    at Module../src/components/layout.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=ecebbf8c&scoped=true&lang=css& (main.js:313)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:579)
    at eval (VM655 layout.vue:7)
    at Module../src/components/layout.vue (main.js:256)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:579)
    at eval (index.js:3)
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        main: './src/index.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'assets/[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    devServer: {
        port:9000,
        index: 'index.htm',
        host: 'hello.local'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                use: [
                    'vue-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.pug$/,
                use: [
                    'pug-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.pug',
            filename: 'index.htm',
            inject: true
        })
    ]
}
```

index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Hello from './components/hello.vue';

Vue.component('hello', Hello)

new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

index.pug

```
html
    body
        #app
            hello
```

hello.vue

```
<template>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</template>

<style scoped>
    h1
    {
        color:blue;
    }
</style>

<script>
export default {
    
}
</script>
```

Resultant HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <hello></hello>
        </div>
        <script src="/assets/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for me was to extract the css using mini-css-extract-plugin. Updated webpack config is:

```
const path = require('path');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        main: './src/index.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'assets/[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    devServer: {
        port:9000,
        index: 'index.htm',
        host: 'hello.local'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                use: [
                    'vue-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.pug$/,
                use: [
                    'pug-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.pug',
            filename: 'index.htm',
            inject: true
        })
    ]
}
```

Plan was to extract CSS later so unsure why this didn't work with the original config. If anyone can guide me to the reason, that would be great!